# Integrate a fingerprinter in web application C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, webforms, fingerprint

I am developing a web application in C# with VS 2012.

I have a fingerprinter which contains SDK in Windows Forms format, but my project is web. I can communicate the windows forms project with the web project, so I can open and close the fingerprinter. Also I can put this in read mode, so when I put my finger in the sensor the event of read (which is called `OnRead`) is fired in the windows forms project.

But I have one problem. After the sensor reads three times my finger, it fires other event (which is called `OnEnroll`) automatically. This event computes the fingerprint and then I can store this in a DB, etc. If I execute the Windows Forms project all works fine.

But if I execute the web project, which communicates with the windows forms project, after the sensor read three times the finger, nothing happens. The event `OnEnroll` isn't fired.

Any idea?

Comment: Code in a web site is going to run in IIS, which will be remote and won't have access to the user's machine & their peripherals (except through any Javascript tricks, Java applets, or ActiveX controls or the like)

Comment: The sensor is on the server machine, in the same place where the WebForm is compiled.